# laravel and vue.js - how to install ckeditor

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I am looking for way to install Ckedior in laravel and vue.js comopnent.

I installed ckeditor using

```
composer require ckeditor/ckeditor
```

Now I want to implement this in my **component**, but I cant find how to do it..

Comment: In your VueJS script, remember to `require` the `ckeditor.js` file. When your component is mounted, you can simply initialize ckeditor in it. Assuming that you have a textarea in the component, you can use `<textarea id="editor">` and then call `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );` in the [mounted lifecycle callback](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).

Comment: @Terry, thanks for response, i done that. One think i need to know its how to require ckeditor.js. It is in my vendor folder.

Comment: It depends what you're using to build your site. If you are using webpack (or bower or the likes), then using `require(...)` is rather trivial. If you have no build steps for your JS, simply load the script file manually on the page itself. Since you are using composer, check this: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_package_managers